# Adding namespace to imported third-party package in Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I am importing a third-party package into my project using composer.

The `composer.json` of the package autoloads its classes using `"classmap"`:

```
{
  ...
  "name"=>"vendor/project",
  ...
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.2.0"
  },
  "type": "library",
  "include-path":["src/"],
  "classmap": [
    "src/path/to/lib1",
    "src/path/to/lib2"
  ]
  ...
}
```

My project `composer.json` pulls the package in using `"require"`.

```
{
  ...
  "require": {
    "vendor/project": "m.n.*",
  }
  ...
}
```

I'd like to add a namespace that can prefix all the classes of that package when I use it in my project, can I do this in composer?

I am aware I can use autoload at the level of my project, but presumably these classes don't need loading again and where do I point it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a namespace to a project without editing every individual file in the project and adding a `namespace ..` declaration at its top. This is likely infeasible.

If you namespace your own code, there should be no possible problem of a name clash.
If the library clashes with yet another non-namespaced third party library which you also cannot feasibly namespace, then you're in trouble. Unless this is the case, there's no real reason to worry about it.

If composer's definition is set up properly, all you should need to do is simply use the class:

```
$foo = new \VendorClass;
```

Composer's autoloading will take care of loading the class, a missing namespace is of no concern (see above).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description